# Laravel: how to "disable" a global scope in order to include "inactive" objects into query?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am having trouble with global scopes, especially the removal of the scope.

In my User model, i have a ActivatedUsersTrait, that introduces a global scope to only query for Users with the column "activated" set to true (The User is "activated" after email verification).

So far everything works fine, when i query for User::all(), i only get Users with activated=true.

My problem now is, how to include the non-activated Users into my query, like SoftDeletingTrait does via withTrashed()? This is only relevant in my ActivationController, where i need to get the User, set activated=true and save them back to db.

I've created a withInactive() method in my ActiveUsersTrait, based on the method i found in SoftDeletingTrait, but when i run a query on User::withInactive->get(), the non-activated Users won't show up in the results.

Here's my ActiveUsersTrait:

```
use PB\Scopes\ActiveUsersScope;

trait ActiveUsersTrait {

    public static function bootActiveUsersTrait()
    {
        static::addGlobalScope(new ActiveUsersScope);
    }

    public static function withInactive()
    {
        // dd(new static);
        return (new static)->newQueryWithoutScope(new ActiveUsersScope);
    }

    public function getActivatedColumn()
    {
        return 'activated';
    }

    public function getQualifiedActivatedColumn()
    {
        return $this->getTable().'.'.$this->getActivatedColumn();
    }

}
```

and my ActiveUsersScope:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ScopeInterface;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

class ActiveUsersScope implements ScopeInterface {

    public function apply(Builder $builder)
    {
        $model = $builder->getModel();

        $builder->where($model->getQualifiedActivatedColumn(), true);

    }

    public function remove(Builder $builder)
    {
        $column = $builder->getModel()->getQualifiedActivatedColumn();

        $query = $builder->getQuery();

        foreach ((array) $query->wheres as $key => $where)
        {
            if ($this->isActiveUsersConstraint($where, $column))
            {
                unset($query->wheres[$key]);

                $query->wheres = array_values($query->wheres);
            }
        }
    }

    protected function isActiveUsersConstraint(array $where, $column)
    {
        return $where['type'] == 'Basic' && $where['column'] == $column;
    }
}
```

Any help is highly appreciated!

Thanks in advance! -Joseph

Comment: Might be a bit old now but i've added a better solution having run into the same problem myself if you'd care to take a look :)

Comment: @FreezeDriedPop Mind adding credits? http://softonsofa.com/laravel-how-to-define-and-use-eloquent-global-scopes/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The SoftDeletingTrait where cleanup is simpler because it doesn't involve any bindings (it's a "Null" where, not a "Basic" where). The issue you're encountering is that the binding for [ n => true ] is still there, even when you manually remove the where.

I'm thinking about making a PR because I encountered the same issue myself, and there isn't a great way to keep track of which wheres and which bindings go together.

If you are only using a simple query, you can keep track of the index of the binding more or less like so:

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ScopeInterface;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

class ActiveUsersScope implements ScopeInterface {

    /**
     * The index in which we added a where clause
     * @var int
     */
    private $where_index;

    /**
     * The index in which we added a where binding
     * @var int
     */
    private $binding_index;

    /**
     * Apply the scope to a given Eloquent query builder.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder  $builder
     * @return void
     */
    public function apply(Builder $builder)
    {
        $model = $builder->getModel();

        $builder->where($model->getQualifiedActivatedColumn(), true);

        $this->where_index = count($query->wheres) - 1;

        $this->binding_index = count($query->getRawBindings()['where']) - 1;
    }

    /**
     * Remove the scope from the given Eloquent query builder.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder  $builder
     * @return void
     */
    public function remove(Builder $builder)
    {
        $query = $builder->getQuery();

        unset($query->wheres[$this->where_index]);
        $where_bindings = $query->getRawBindings()['where'];
        unset($where_bindings[$this->binding_index]);
        $query->setBindings(array_values($where_bindings));
        $query->wheres = array_values($query->wheres);
    }
}
```

Note how we're storing the indices where the where clause and bindings were added, rather than looping through and checking if we found the right one. This almost feels like a better design—we added the where clause and binding, so we should know where it is without having to loop through all where clauses. Of course, it will all go haywire if something else (like `::withTrashed`) is also messing with the where array. Unfortunately, the where bindings and where clauses are just flat arrays, so we can't exactly listen on changes to them. A more object-oriented approach with better automatic management of the dependency between clauses and their binding(s) would be preferred.

Obviously this approach could benefit from some prettier code and validation that array keys exists, etc. But this should get you started. Since the global scopes aren't singletons (they get applied whenever `newQuery()` is invoked) this approach should be valid without that extra validation.

Hope this helps under the heading of "good enough for now"!

Comment: Hey OP, does this help?

Comment: Hey! Many thanks for your answer! Sorry, didn't notice before – will check and respond tomorrow!

Comment: There seems to be a different issue with my code - when i execute
`User::query()->getQuery()->toSql();`
i get
`select * from \`users\` where \`users\`.\`deleted_at\` is null and \`users\`.\`activated\` = ?`

on
`User::withInactive()->getQuery()->toSql();`
i get
`select * from \`users\` where \`users\`.\`deleted_at\` is null`
which are the expected queries. But still the withInactive() query doesn't return any results. Not even the active ones… So identifiying and removing the where doesn't seem to be an issue in my case.

Comment: Yes, I think it will still be your problem, because the problem is the leftover binding, not the query. Check ```User::withInactive()->getBindings()``` and I think you'll see what I mean.

Comment: you should add `unset($where_bindings[$this->binding_index]);` in your `remove()` method before `$query->setBindings(array_values($where_bindings));`

Comment: This solved my problem as well. Have my upvote, sir.

Comment: Here's something that makes defining global scopes a breeze https://github.com/jarektkaczyk/laravel-global-scope

Answer (score 61):

Eloquent queries now have a `withoutGlobalScopes()` method.

See: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#query-scopes (under the Removing Global Scopes subheading).

From the docs:

```
// Remove one scope
User::withoutGlobalScope(AgeScope::class)->get();

// Remove all of the global scopes...
User::withoutGlobalScopes()->get();

// Remove some of the global scopes...
User::withoutGlobalScopes([
    FirstScope::class, SecondScope::class
])->get();
```

Comment: Awesome, love the solution where you can list the scopes in an array excluding only specific ones.

Comment: how can i implement new method in my trait like withTrashed() OnlyTrashed()  , to revert back the query that applied by my globalScope to make available to other developers to deactivate my globalscope whenever he wants

Answer (score 0):

Just found this after having the same problem and I have a more eloquent solution. Simply replace your "remove" method with this.

```
/**
 * Remove the scope from the given Eloquent query builder.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder  $builder
 * @return void
 */
public function remove(Builder $builder)
{
    $query = $builder->getQuery();

    $column = $builder->getModel()->getQualifiedActivatedColumn();

    foreach ((array) $query->wheres as $key => $where)
    {
        if ($this->isActiveUsersConstraint($where, $column))
        {
            // Here SoftDeletingScope simply removes the where
            // but since we use Basic where (not Null type)
            // we need to get rid of the binding as well
            $this->removeWhere($query, $key);

            $this->removeBinding($query, $key);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Remove scope constraint from the query.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder  $builder
 * @param  int  $key
 * @return void
 */
protected function removeWhere($query, $key)
{
    unset($query->wheres[$key]);

    $query->wheres = array_values($query->wheres);
}

/**
 * Remove scope constraint from the query.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder  $builder
 * @param  int  $key
 * @return void
 */
protected function removeBinding($query, $key)
{
    $bindings = $query->getRawBindings()['where'];

    unset($bindings[$key]);

    $query->setBindings(array_values($bindings));
}
```

Comment: Does this work if any of the wheres have multiple bindings (e.g. in the event of a whereRaw...)?

Comment: I haven't tested that particular scenario.

Comment: Yeah. I'm thinking the actual problem is that query grammar segments get dumped into an array, and binding segments get dumped into an array, and they're not "aware" of each other in any sense. Similarly, my solution above doesn't work if you apply two different scopes in the same way and then try to remove them both in the same way—the index will move around the second time you try it.

Comment: So what I'm saying, Freeze Dried Pop, is the only "elegant" solution is refactoring grammars and bindings to be stateful with respect to each other. That's a pretty big refactoring, but I think the performance impact would be minimal and the benefit would be huge.

Comment: You're right and this would be a good thing to bring up as an issue on the github repo.

Comment: Source of this code: http://softonsofa.com/laravel-how-to-define-and-use-eloquent-global-scopes/ And btw there's a little error in your answer - methods `removeWhere` and `removeBinding` accept `Query\Builder` not `Eloquent\Builder`

Answer (score 0):

Look at the newQuey function (Eloquent/Model.php Lvl 4.2):

```
newQuery{
//'initialized' 
$b = $this->newQueryWithoutScopes();  //Get a 'clean' query. Note the plural.  
//and applies scopes
return $this->applyGlobalScopes($b);  //now builder is 'dirty'
}
```

So, this suggests a solution:

```
function someButNotAllScopes(){
$b = $this->newQueryWithoutScopes();
$unwanted = new MyUnwantedScope();
//get all scopes, but skip the one(s) you dont want
foreach($this->getGlobalScopes as $s){
 if ($s instanceof $unwanted){continue;}
  $s->apply($b, $this)
}
return $b;
}
```

You can also do something clever with scopes. Make em implement and OnOffInterface with an 'applyMe' method. This method can 'turn' on/off the apply method of a scope. In the function above you can get the unswanted scope and 'turn' if off:

```
$scope = $this->getGlobalScope(new Unwanted());
$scope->applyme(false); //will turn off the apply method
return $this->newQuery();  //now each scope checks if it is 'off'
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply, you can apply without bindings like so:

```
$builder->where($column, new \Illuminate\Database\Query\Expression(1));
```

or

```
$builder->where($column, \DB::raw(1));
```