# laravel eloquent override parent query to remove condition

Tags: php, eloquent, orm

I am trying to access a Model that uses a a Global condition where facality_id. I am using the newQuery function to override the Query but i am not able to remove the where condition.

My code is like

```
 /**
 * 
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
 */
public function newQuery($excludeDeleted = true)
{
   $builder = parent::newQuery($excludeDeleted);

    Need to how can i remove the Where in the parent Query

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel: how to "disable" a global scope in order to include "inactive" objects into query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25312386/laravel-how-to-disable-a-global-scope-in-order-to-include-inactive-objects)

Comment: How have you defined the global scope? In a separate class or as anonymous function in `boot` method?